# Need to Hard Refresh in npm run watch

Tags: laravel, vue.js, browser

I'm using Laravel with Vue JS. Most of the time, I use `npm run watch` than other commands.

While I modify contents in my VUE template, I've to press `Ctrl+Shift+R` or hard refresh to actually see the modified content in the browser.

Another alternative I can do is checking "Disable cache" in Developer Tool (Network > Disable Cache)

Is it meant to be worked like that or are there any sort of steps to run without hitting hard refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers will cache assets by default. This is to prevent the need to re-download the assets (javascript, css, etc) on every page load. Hard refreshing will force re-downloading of said assets. To prevent this, you need to enable some form of "cache busting", which essentially appends a unique hash to said files, thus forcing the browser to re-download them without the need for a user to clear their cache or to force a refresh.

Laravel mix includes this feature and can be enabled in the webpack.mix.js file.

For example, inside your webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .version();
```

Then, when importing in your blade view, make sure you use the mix helper:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

You can find more information about versioning / cache busting here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting